# When scanning input from a file to a struct, and then saving the changes, why does it always write to the first line and erases everything else?

Tags: c, file, struct

So for my school project im making a program which makes a user profile with some basic information. This information is saved in the following struct, however when i try and change one of the parameters in the saved profile, say the age. I load the profile into the struct, ask the user what they want to change, then change it. Then close up by running the profile saver which saved all the information (which has now been changed)

The problem im having trouble with is, that when i change something within the struct and then try to save the changes it saves the change how it is supposed to, however it erases everything else in the file, which in turn ruins the loader, as the strings are no longer present i presume

```
struct profile_info
{
char first_name[30];
char last_name[30];
char gender;
int age;
int height;
double weight;
}user_profile;
```

profile saver

```
/* this function til take the data inputted from the user and save to a .txt
file on the local pc */
void profile_saver(struct profile_info user_profile)
{
FILE *file_pointer;

file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

fprintf(file_pointer, "%s\n%s\n %c\n%d\n%d\n%lf", user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name,
user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height, user_profile.weight);

fclose(file_pointer);
}
```

and the profile loader

```
/* this function will load the user profile if such a profile exists */
void user_profile_loader(struct profile_info user_profile)
{
FILE *file_pointer;
file_pointer = fopen("test.txt", "r");

fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", user_profile.first_name);

fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", user_profile.last_name);

fscanf(file_pointer, " %c", &(user_profile.gender));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.age));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%d", &(user_profile.height));

fscanf(file_pointer, "%lf", &(user_profile.weight));

printf("Following profile has been loaded \n%s \n%s \n%c \n%d \n%d \n%lf\n", user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name,
user_profile.gender, user_profile.age, user_profile.height,     user_profile.weight);

fclose(file_pointer);
}
```

Finally, the changer, explained in the start

```
void profile_changer(struct profile_info user_profile)
{
int user_change_choice;

user_profile_loader(user_profile);

printf("What would you like to change? \nFirst name > 1 \nLast name > 2 \nGender > 3 \nAge > 4 \nHeight > 5 \nWeight > 6");
scanf("%d", &user_change_choice);

switch(user_change_choice)
    {
    case 1:
    printf("Please enter your new first name ");
    scanf("%s", user_profile.first_name);
    break;
    case 2:
    printf("Please enter your new last name ");
    scanf("%s", user_profile.last_name);
    break;
    case 3:
    printf("Please enter your new gender ");
    scanf(" %c", &(user_profile.gender));
    break;
    case 4:
    printf("Please enter your new age ");
    scanf("%d", &(user_profile.age));
    break;
    case 5:
    printf("Please enter your new heigt ");
    scanf("%d", &(user_profile.height));
    break;
    case 6:
    printf("Please enter your new weight ");
    scanf("%lf", &(user_profile.weight));
    }

profile_saver(user_profile);

}
```

Comment: @user3121023, Wil try it out, though wouldn't append just put the edits at the end of the file?

Comment: @user3121023 But that is not what i'm seeking, im seeking to change a single line in the file, but loading it, and then chaging it, then saving it again :-) Tried it out, and did as expected, put the information at the end of teh file, where the loader doesn't find it, since it only loads the first 6 lines from the file :-)

Comment: @user3121023, why would this be required? since everything has static memory needs, the arrays never change size [30] and the int / doubles are static sizes aswell?
2nd Note, if i change the first name, to the exact same, it still changes everything after the name to either 0 (the int / doubles / char) and the 2nd string to "" (aka nothing)

Comment: @user3121023 while I agree that only letters up to the \n is copied over to the file when the file is made, this does not equal that the next string will follow it immediately after right? since I allocate space in the heap for 29 chars and a null terminator the next string should not immediate after the previous string, but after the (in case of bob) the 25 blanks chars and a null terminator, would follow after the \n no?

Comment: @user3121023, on the int / char / double I disagree with you, wouldn't the int's when saved in the program always take up 8 bits for a double, since a double is a double no matter it's value it will always be a double which uses up 8 bits of memory?

Comment: @user3121023, exactly, and since the array has a size of 30, entering 'bob\n' would mean you have an array that says

`'b''o''b''\n'' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''\0'` (where spaces mean nothing, not an actual white space) right?

I'll try and look up a precision specifier :-)

Comment: scanf add the terminating char.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, I said to use "%29s" but what happens if you pass less  chars? scanf takes care to pad it and put the terminating at the 30 chars?

Comment: @user3121023 Yep, the printf will do the work!

Comment: @user3121023, i got an answer down below, have a look at it as it solved my problem and confirmed my theory that the next string does indeed start later(when the rest of the blank array is terminated by \0), else his answer to the problem would not work since the problem would still be present :-)

Comment: @terencehill, look at my above comment to look at the answer for clearing of the problem, and my assumption that an array of 30 will indeed be in the cae of bob as i stated above, since if the problem was with string formatting his solution would not fix the problem :-)

Comment: To change a single line in the file.  First iterate through the file, reading a line at a time until the desired line is read.  modify the data read from that line.  call `fseek()` to step the 'file pointer' back the length of the line, then call `fprintf()`.  Note: `file pointer` is a concept of the current location in the file where the next read/write operation will be performed, NOT the variable of a similar name in the posted code.

Comment: the current method of reading the variables from the file `fscanf()` will not properly handle any padding bytes in the struct instance in the file.  Suggest reading the whole struct into a instance of the struct using only one call to `read()` then the fields are already aligned and updating is simple.  to keep everything in alignment, replace the call to `fprintf()` with `write()` and write the whole struct in one statement.  Use `fseek( file_pointer, -sizeof( struct), SEEK_CUR);`  to properly position the 'file pointer' before calling `write()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you have defined your structure globally. When you write this :

```
struct profile_info
{
char first_name[30];
char last_name[30];
char gender;
int age;
int height;
double weight;
}user_profile;
```

It means that you have defined a new structure, and have declared a global variable `user_profile` which is an object of this structure. When you call the `user_profile_loader(user_profile)` function, you are making a copy of the `user_profile` variable and sending it to the `user_profile_loader` function. Now you are accepting values to the new variable rather than the `user_profile` variable, just their names are same, scope is different. As the function exits, it does not make changes to the `user_profile` variable, and the data is actually not loading to your `user_profile` function, but in the other temporary variable.

When you call the `profile_saver(user_profile)` function, you are again passing the `user_profile` variable to write to disk, but remember, it was never loaded, and has no values assigned to it! So it writes nothing to the disk. So the problem is with your `user_profile_loader` function.

Solution :

Since your `user_profile` function is global, you need not pass it to other functions, since they have direct access to the variable beforehand. Change the definitions of the functions to this :

```
void profile_saver(){
/*code*/
}

void user_profile_loader(){
/*code*/
}
```

In the `profile_changer()` function, make the following changes :

```
void profile_changer()
{
int user_change_choice;
user_profile_loader();
printf("What would you like to change? \nFirst name > 1 \nLast name > 2 \nGender > 3 \nAge > 4 \nHeight > 5 \nWeight > 6");
scanf("%d", &user_change_choice);
switch(user_change_choice)
{
case 1:
printf("Please enter your new first name ");
scanf("%s", user_profile.first_name);
break;
case 2:
printf("Please enter your new last name ");
scanf("%s", user_profile.last_name);
break;
case 3:
printf("Please enter your new gender ");
scanf(" %c", &(user_profile.gender));
break;
case 4:
printf("Please enter your new age ");
scanf("%d", &(user_profile.age));
break;
case 5:
printf("Please enter your new heigt ");
scanf("%d", &(user_profile.height));
break;
case 6:
printf("Please enter your new weight ");
scanf("%lf", &(user_profile.weight));
}

profile_saver();
}
```

No changes are required for your other two function codes. I hope this would do your task.

Comment: Yes! The struct was indeed called created globally

I tried changing all funtion calls and functions to have blank `void some_function();` which solved the problem! thanks for the great explanation, really gave me a clear picture both to why it wasnt working, but also why it was posting in blank spaces / zero's!

Thanks again!!